# yfinance SP500 ticker.info into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I want to store the "info" from a list of the SP500 symbols in a Pandas DataFrame.

I can do this one at a time (df1, df2,...) and then append all into one DataFrame (df):

[image: Code]

but would like to have a function that automates this by iterating through a list of symbols and appends new rows each time to 'df'.

Any ideas?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

l = ['AAPL', 'MMM']

df_list = []

for t in l:
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame([yf.Ticker(t).info]))

df = pd.concat(df_list)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load one and then loop through the list of the others:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

# first stock
data=yf.Ticker('AAPL')
dfall= pd.DataFrame([data.info])

# list of the others
liststock=['MMM','GOOG','MSFT']

# append all
for stock in liststock:
    data=yf.Ticker(stock)
    df= pd.DataFrame([data.info])
    dfall=pd.concat([dfall, df],axis=0)
```